# select multiple columns from Top 1 row by group in R

Tags: r

Given the following "data" data.frame:

```
state   city            cost
CA      Los Angeles     12
CA      Fresno          7
CA      San Francisco   14
TX      Austin          10
TX      Dallas          8
```

I need to get the top 1 city with the lowest cost by state. In the case above the result would be:

```
state   city    cost
CA      Fresno  7
TX      Dallas  8
```

`with(data, tapply(cost, state, min)`) gives me the following results:

```
CA   TX
7    8
```

Please point me to the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sqldf package you can do:

```
library(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("select * from data group by state having MIN(cost)")
```

Comment: Dusan, do you know how this would be if I need "top n" order by cost? That's really what I need to accomplish. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
      group_by(state) %>%
       top_n(1, -cost)
#    state   city cost
#1    CA Fresno    7
#2    TX Dallas    8
```

Or use `slice`

```
data %>% 
     group_by(state) %>% 
     arrange(cost) %>% 
     slice(1)
#   state   city cost
#1    CA Fresno    7
#2    TX Dallas    8
```

Or a `base R` option is

```
 data[with(data, !!ave(cost, state, FUN=function(x) x==min(x))),]
```